# Python - For loop that performes a sum and stores answer in new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, for-loop

I would like to calculate the total age of all persons with the same name:    See the example table here.

[table with names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iDco.jpg)

This is the code I have written so far.. but it is not complete and it doesn't work..

```
final_df = DataFrame()  

for i in [list of names]:
dummy = sort_df.loc[sort_df['name'] == i]    
total_age = 0   

for j in dummy.age:       
    age2 = dummy.age(j)

    total_age = total_age + age2

    final_df.append(total_age)


final_df['total_age'] = total_age
```

How do I fix this problem and I can write a code that will iterate over ages of people with the same name and sum them and store these in a new column?

In the end it should look like this:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxbUU.jpg)

Comment: You are missing indentation for the first for loop. Since you tagged `csv` is all your data in a csv file?

Comment: Yes I have got a csv file with all 2 columns: names and ages.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't iterate over a list, but over the csv file?

Comment: I am going to re-ask this question, because I see things are missing :( Thanks for your tip Moon Cheesez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code I assume there is one csv file named `input.csv` which has already been read to `sort_df` with this data inside:

```
name,age,total age
Alfredo,13,
Alfredo,12,
Alfredo,15,
Jaap,12,
Jaap,14,
Koen,16,
Lian,76,
Lian,45,
Lian,34,
Lian,14,
```

In this case, there is no need to declare another `dummy` dataframe. Use this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

sort_df = DataFrame.from_csv("inCSV.txt", index_col=False)
final_df = sort_df

# Use a dictionary to keep track instead
total_age = {}
for name in sort_df["name"]:
    if name not in total_age.keys():
        total_age[name] = 0

# Add up the ages
for index in xrange(len(sort_df)):
    person = sort_df.loc[index]
    name = person["name"]
    age = person["age"]
    total_age[name] += age

# Set the new ages into final_df
for index in xrange(len(final_df)):
    person = final_df.loc[index]
    name = person["name"]
    final_df.set_value(index, "total age", total_age[name])

print final_df
```

which will give you (in `final_df`):

```
      name  age  total age
0  Alfredo   13       40.0
1  Alfredo   12       40.0
2  Alfredo   15       40.0
3     Jaap   12       26.0
4     Jaap   14       26.0
5     Koen   16       16.0
6     Lian   76      169.0
7     Lian   45      169.0
8     Lian   34      169.0
9     Lian   14      169.0
```

Answer (score 1):

For example data,

```
name,age
Alfredo,13,
Alfredo,12,
Alfredo,15,
Jaap,12,
Jaap,14,
Koen,16,
Lian,76,
Lian,45,
Lian,34,
Lian,14,

import csv
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(int)
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file_handle)
for person in reader:
    name = person['name'].lower()
    age = int(person['age'])
    result[name] += age
>>> result
defaultdict(int, {'alfredo': 40, 'jaap': 26, 'koen': 16, 'lian': 169})
```

To update the file with `result`

```
# make a reader object    
# make a writer object with fieldnames ['name', 'age', 'total_age']
# write header
for person in reader:
    person.update({'total_age': result[person['name'].lower()]})
    writer.writerow(person)
```

Answer (score 0):

you find the answer here :

```
from collections import defaultdict
list_name = [
{'age': 25, 'name': 'alfredo'},
{'age': 44, 'name': 'alfredo'},
{'age': 23, 'name': 'jaap'},
{'age': 60, 'name': 'jaap'}
]

k={}
c = defaultdict(int)
for d in list_name:
     c[d['name']] += d['age']
     k[d['name']] = c[d['name']]
for d in list_name:
    d['total_age'] = k[d['name']] 
print list_name
```